# How to run a program on Computer B when Computer A opens a webpage

Tags: php, applescript, p2p, automator

I have an iPad running Kiosk Software.  When the user touches a button, it goes to a URL (which I can specify).  Pretty much everything else is locked out.

I want to notify the receptionist (immediately when the button is pushed on the Kiosk) that I would like to have a FaceTime session, so the receptionist can start the session.  I have an applescript on the receptionists desk that does this.

I have researched using different approaches but so far they are all beyond my current abilities.

Any suggestions of what may be a simple approach?   I have looked at using growl notification or "put"ing the Kiosk name into the URL and using PHP on the webpage but not quite sure how to get the program to run on the receptionists computer.

I have some experience with HTML, applescript, automator, and javascript but its pretty basic.

Comment: Could you use something like this?
http://clickontyler.com/php-growl/

Comment: when I read the skills you are claiming to have , and when I look at the job that needs to be done , it looks like it's impossible to happened. You would need a little bit more then just having basic understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the iPad and receptionist are on the same local network, this is how I would do it.

1. Turn on the webserver on the receptionists computer (System Preferences > Sharing > Web Sharing)
2. Copy down the url. It will look something like:

   ```
   http://192.168.1.130/~receptionists_username/
   ```
3. Create a .php file in the receptionists /Users/receptionists_username/Sites directory called "faceTime.php"
4. Make that .php file read something like

   ```
   <?php `osascript /path/to/your/apple_script.scptd` ?>
   ```
5. Change your Kiosk button url to:

   ```
   http://192.168.1.130/~receptionists_username/faceTime.php
   ```